# IPSec/GRE over Metro-E traffic question

Tags: ipsec, metro-ethernet

I am trying to run IPSec GRE over a MetroE circuit:

```
ROUTER---------metroe----------ROUTER
```

The routers are set up to route all traffic over the ipsec tunnel; however, when I check the routers I see traffic on both the tunnel and the physical interface.  Why is that?

I want the traffic to only go through the tunnel interface.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

> I see traffic on both the tunnel and the physical interface. Why is
>   that?

The tunnel is virtual between two routers, but it is still leaving a physical interface; that means the counters on the physical interface will increase.   The IPSec/GRE tunnel has to go somewhere.

Comment: Why do I see the RX|TX counters increasing on the pyhsical interface when it supposed to go via the tunnel?

Comment: @user3916 Because the tunnel goes over the physical interface.  _Note:_ the traffic going into the interfaces are going to be different (i.e. the physical interface will be encrypted data).